# Change tracking / Inventory - Data collection rule script JSON

Tags: azure, templates

I am not able to create a Data Collection Rule for collecting Change tracking and Inventory changes. There is a provided JSON script on MS Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking/change-tracking-data-collection-rule-creation)

Deploying custom template -> importing JSON file -> verification failed (Invalid Template)

`{ "code": "InvalidTemplate", "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'subscriptionId' is not valid: Unable to evaluate the template language function 'substring'. The length parameter cannot be less than zero. The length parameter: '-16'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-function-substring for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-functions for usage details.'." }`

Any idea what could be wrong?

It is related to Docs about Azure Automation and Azure Monitoring Agents (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking/enable-vms-monitoring-agent?tabs=singlevm%2Carcvm)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the full Resource ID of the Workspace in the template for the workspaceResourceId parameter; e.g.,

```
/subscriptions/<subscription_id/resourceGroups/<rg_name>/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/<law_name>
```